# How can I trigger the push notification from the site to the java application on a webviews

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, firebase

I create a site, I put the site on a java webview, I have a chat system made in js and php and I'm trying to understand how can I trigger the push notification and save the token fcm in the session of the site.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Trova la WebView tramite il suo ID univoco
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web);

        // Attiva il debug solo in modalità di debug
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("chat")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Daje cazzo";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Tacci tua";
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Ottieni il token FCM
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Ottieni il nuovo token Instance ID
                        String token = task.getResult();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Token FCM: " + token);

                        // Invia il token al tuo server app, se necessario.
                        // sendRegistrationToServer(token);

                        // Mostra un alert nel JavaScript del tuo sito web con il token FCM
                        webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('Token FCM: " + token + "');", null);
                    }
                });


        // Abilita JavaScript
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Imposta un WebViewClient per gestire il caricamento degli URL all'interno della WebView
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // Imposta un WebChromeClient per la gestione dell'input dei file
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        // Passa il contesto dell'attività alla WebView per utilizzarlo da JavaScript
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        // Controlla la connettività prima di caricare l'URL
        if (isInternetConnected()) {
            // Se c'è connessione, carica l'URL nella WebView
            webView.loadUrl("mysite");
        } else {
            // Se non c'è connessione, mostra un messaggio di errore o una pagina di fallback
            webView.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Errore di connessione. Controlla la tua connessione di rete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();

            // Check if the URL matches your allowed domain
            if (url.startsWith("mysite")) {
                // Load the URL in the WebView
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false; // Returning false means the WebView handles the URL
            } else if (url.startsWith("https://www.instagram.com")) {
                // Open Instagram links in the Instagram app
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android"); // Package

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // If Instagram app is not installed, handle the exception
                    Log.e(TAG, "Instagram app not installed", e);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Instagram app not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return true; // Returning true means the WebView does not handle the URL
            } else {
                // Open external links in the default browser or handle them based on your requirements
                // For example, open all external links in the default browser
                // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                // startActivity(intent);

                return false; // Returning false means the WebView handles the URL
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Memorizza il callback per l'uso successivo
            MainActivity.this.filePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            // Avvia l'intent per selezionare un file
            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            return true;
        }
    }

    // Gestisci il risultato dell'intent per la selezione del file
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (filePathCallback != null) {
                Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data);
                filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
                filePathCallback = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Metodo per verificare la connessione a Internet
    private boolean isInternetConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Dichiarare il launcher nella parte superiore della tua Activity/Fragment:
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) {
                    // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
                    askNotificationPermission();
                } else {
                    // TODO: Inform user that that your app will not show notifications.
                }
            });

    // Ask the perms for sending the notify
    private void askNotificationPermission() {
        // This is only necessary for API level >= 33 (TIRAMISU)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
            } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
                // TODO: display an educational UI explaining to the user the features that will be enabled
                //       by them granting the POST_NOTIFICATION permission. This UI should provide the user
                //       "OK" and "No thanks" buttons. If the user selects "OK," directly request the permission.
            } else {
                // Directly ask for the permission
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

chat.php

```
<?php
include_once "navbar.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
}
?>
<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>

<style>
    .nav {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>

<section class="chat-area">
    <header style="background-color: white; z-index: 99999999 !important">
        <?php
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['unique_id']);
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE unique_id = $user_id");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        } else {
            header("location: users.php");
        }

        $myid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['unique_id']);
        ?>
        
        <a href="users.php" class="back-icon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <?php
        if (isset($row['img_1'])) {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $row['img_1']; ?>" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%">
        <?php
        } else {
            echo '<img src="profili/noimg.png" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%">';
        }
        ?>
        <a href="mysite/profilo?token=<?php echo $row['token'];?>" style="color: var(--dark)">
            <div class="details" style="z-index: 100 !important">
                <div class="pb-4"></div>
            <span><?php echo $row['username']; ?></span>
            <p><?php if($row['status'] == 'Inattivo'){echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: var(--secondary) !important; font-size: 0.9rem !important"></i>';} else {echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: var(--success) !important; font-size: 0.9rem !important"></i>';} echo $row['status']; ?></p>
        </div>
        </a>
  </header>
    <div class="pb-4"></div>
    <div class="pb-4"></div>
    <div class="pb-4"></div>
    <div class="chat-box" style="z-index: 1 !important">

    </div>
    <form action="#" class="typing-area" style="background-color: var(--dark) !important">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="incoming_id" name="incoming_id" id="incoming_msg_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
            <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field form-control input-messaggio" placeholder="Scrivi un messaggio..." autocomplete="off">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>

<script>
  function eseguiRichiestaAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST', // o 'PUT' a seconda della tua implementazione
        data: {
            incoming_msg_id: <?php echo $myid ?>,
            outgoing_msg_id: <?php echo $user_id ?>,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.error("Errore nella richiesta Ajax:", status, error);
}

    });
}

// Esegui la richiesta ogni 500 ms
setInterval(eseguiRichiestaAjax, 500);

</script>

<script src="javascript/chat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add this link to load the jQuery UI library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Bootstrap version 5 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Add this script at the end of your HTML page -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

chat.js

```
const form = document.querySelector(".typing-area"),
    incoming_id = form.querySelector(".incoming_id").value,
    inputField = form.querySelector(".input-field"),
    sendBtn = form.querySelector("button"),
    chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");

let buttonEnabled = true; // Flag per tenere traccia dello stato del bottone

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

inputField.focus();
inputField.onkeyup = () => {
    if (inputField.value.trim() !== "") {
        sendBtn.classList.add("active");
    } else {
        sendBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

// ...

// Array per memorizzare i messaggi temporanei in attesa di essere inviati
const tempMessagesQueue = [];
let isProcessingMessages = false; // Flag per evitare di avviare più di un processo di invio

sendBtn.onclick = () => {
    if (!buttonEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    buttonEnabled = false;

    const tempMessage = createTempMessage(inputField.value);
    chatBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tempMessage);
    scrollToBottom();

    tempMessagesQueue.push({
        message: inputField.value,
        timestamp: Date.now(), // Add a timestamp for sorting purposes
        callback: sendTempMessages
    });

    inputField.value = "";

    if (navigator.onLine && !isProcessingMessages) {
        sendTempMessages();
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        buttonEnabled = true;
    }, 1000);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    tempMessagesQueue.push(...loadTempMessagesFromStorage());
    if (navigator.onLine && tempMessagesQueue.length > 0) {
        sendTempMessages();
    }
});
// ...

function sendTempMessages() {
    isProcessingMessages = true;

    const tempMessageObj = tempMessagesQueue.shift();

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/insert-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                const temporaryMessage = tempMessageObj.tempMessageElement;
                if (temporaryMessage && temporaryMessage.parentNode) {
                    temporaryMessage.parentNode.removeChild(temporaryMessage);
                }

                if (tempMessagesQueue.length > 0) {
                    sendTempMessages();
                } else {
                    isProcessingMessages = false;
                    clearTempMessagesFromStorage(); // Dopo l'invio di tutti i messaggi, cancella dalla localStorage
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Errore durante la richiesta XMLHttpRequest: ', xhr.status);
                handleSendError(tempMessageObj);
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.error('Errore durante l\'invio della richiesta XMLHttpRequest');
        handleSendError(tempMessageObj);
    };

    let formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.set('message', tempMessageObj.message);
    xhr.send(formData);
}


function handleSendError(tempMessageObj) {
    // Gestisci l'errore in base alle tue esigenze
    // Potresti voler lasciare il messaggio temporaneo nella chat o implementare un'altra logica di gestione degli errori.
    if (tempMessagesQueue.length > 0) {
        sendTempMessages();
    } else {
        isProcessingMessages = false;
    }
}

// ...


function removeFromLocalStorage(timestamp) {
    // Retrieve the cached messages from localStorage
    const cachedMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tempMessages')) || [];

    // Remove the message with the specified timestamp
    const updatedMessages = cachedMessages.filter(message => message.timestamp !== timestamp);

    // Update the localStorage with the modified messages
    localStorage.setItem('tempMessages', JSON.stringify(updatedMessages));
}

// ...

// Aggiungi il messaggio alla coda dei messaggi temporanei
tempMessagesQueue.push({
    message: inputField.value,
    timestamp: new Date().getTime() // Aggiungi un timestamp per identificare il messaggio
});

// ...

// Monitora lo stato della connessione e invia i messaggi temporanei quando la connessione torna
window.addEventListener('online', () => {
    if (tempMessagesQueue.length > 0) {
        sendTempMessages();
    }
});
chatBox.onmouseenter = () => {
    chatBox.classList.add("active");
}

chatBox.onmouseleave = () => {
    chatBox.classList.remove("active");
}

setInterval(() => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/get-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                let currentScrollPos = chatBox.scrollHeight - chatBox.clientHeight;
                let isScrolledToBottom = Math.abs(chatBox.scrollTop - currentScrollPos) < 1;

                let data = xhr.response;
                chatBox.innerHTML = data;

                if (!chatBox.classList.contains("active") && isScrolledToBottom) {
                    scrollToBottom();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("incoming_id=" + incoming_id);
}, 500);

// Funzione per creare un messaggio temporaneo
function createTempMessage(message) {
    return '<div class="chat outgoing temporary">' +
        '<div class="details">' +
        '<p>' + message + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    chatBox.style.height = "100vh";
    chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
}

php/get-chat.php


<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
        include_once "../_conf.php";
        $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $output = "";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages LEFT JOIN utenti ON utenti.unique_id = messages.outgoing_msg_id
                WHERE (outgoing_msg_id = $outgoing_id AND incoming_msg_id = $incoming_id)
                OR (outgoing_msg_id = $incoming_id AND incoming_msg_id = $outgoing_id) ORDER BY msg_id";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                if ($row['outgoing_msg_id'] == $outgoing_id) {
                    $result[0]["visualizzato"] = $row['visualizzato'];
                    if($row['visualizzato'] == 1){
                        $color = '#00C1FF';
                    } else {
                        $color = 'CurrentColor';
                    }
                    $data = substr($row['data'], 10, 6);
                    $output .= '<div class="chat outgoing">
                    <div class="details" style="float: right;">
                    <p>' . $row['msg'] . '</p>
                    <b style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0.4rem">' . $row['ora'] . '</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="svg-container" style="margin-top: 18px; float: left;">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 16 11" height="11" width="16" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="" fill="none">
                    <path d="M11.0714 0.652832C10.991 0.585124 10.8894 0.55127 10.7667 0.55127C10.6186 0.55127 10.4916 0.610514 10.3858 0.729004L4.19688 8.36523L1.79112 6.09277C1.7488 6.04622 1.69802 6.01025 1.63877 5.98486C1.57953 5.95947 1.51817 5.94678 1.45469 5.94678C1.32351 5.94678 1.20925 5.99544 1.11192 6.09277L0.800883 6.40381C0.707784 6.49268 0.661235 6.60482 0.661235 6.74023C0.661235 6.87565 0.707784 6.98991 0.800883 7.08301L3.79698 10.0791C3.94509 10.2145 4.11224 10.2822 4.29844 10.2822C4.40424 10.2822 4.5058 10.259 4.60313 10.2124C4.70046 10.1659 4.78086 10.1003 4.84434 10.0156L11.4903 1.59863C11.5623 1.5013 11.5982 1.40186 11.5982 1.30029C11.5982 1.14372 11.5348 1.01888 11.4078 0.925781L11.0714 0.652832ZM8.6212 8.32715C8.43077 8.20866 8.2488 8.09017 8.0753 7.97168C7.99489 7.89128 7.8891 7.85107 7.75791 7.85107C7.6098 7.85107 7.4892 7.90397 7.3961 8.00977L7.10411 8.33984C7.01947 8.43717 6.97715 8.54508 6.97715 8.66357C6.97715 8.79476 7.0237 8.90902 7.1168 9.00635L8.1959 10.0791C8.33132 10.2145 8.49636 10.2822 8.69102 10.2822C8.79681 10.2822 8.89838 10.259 8.99571 10.2124C9.09304 10.1659 9.17556 10.1003 9.24327 10.0156L15.8639 1.62402C15.9358 1.53939 15.9718 1.43994 15.9718 1.32568C15.9718 1.1818 15.9125 1.05697 15.794 0.951172L15.4386 0.678223C15.3582 0.610514 15.2587 0.57666 15.1402 0.57666C14.9964 0.57666 14.8715 0.635905 14.7657 0.754395L8.6212 8.32715Z" fill="' . $color . '"></path>
                    </svg>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
    
    
                } else {
                    $output .= '<div class="chat incoming">
                    <img src="' . $row['img_1'] . '" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%">
                    <div class="details">
                        <p>' . $row['msg'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                    <b style="position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 6vh"><br>' . $row['ora'] . '</b>
                </div>';
                }
                

            }
        }else{
            $output .= '<div><center><b>Nessun messaggio quì.</b></center></div>';
        }
        echo $output;
    }else{
        header("location: ../login.php");
    }
echo '
<style>
.divider {
    height: 4rem; /* regola l\'altezza del separatore in base a 1 em */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .divider {
        height: 2em; /* Regola l\'altezza del separatore per schermi più piccoli */
    }
}

</style>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="divider"></div> <!-- Divider -->
        </div>
    </div>';
?>
```

I want that when a user goes to the account page the token is saved in the database and that when they receive a message from a user, the receiver gets a notification